# i have followed everything from a tutorial but it says unexpected indent on line 6, how can i resolve this

Tags: python, django, django-views, pycharm, django-urls

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from  .models import Post

def post_list_view(request):
  post_objects = Post.objects.all()
  context = {
    'post_objects' : post_objects
  }
return  render(request, "posts/index.html", context)
```

Comment: Indent your `return` into your function...

Answer (score 2):

The return should be inside the function. At the same indent than the rest of the function

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from  .models import Post

def post_list_view(request):
  post_objects = Post.objects.all()
  context = {
    'post_objects' : post_objects
  }
  return render(request, "posts/index.html", context)
```